# How safe is ISAPI folder?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-on-prem

We have TMG Fore Front server, we also have active directory authentication, now if I deploy a web services to ISAPI folder...

How secure it would be ?

E.g. a user can only connect to our site collection after getting authenticated, Is there any case when user can skip connecting to a site collection and have access my custom web services which is in ISAPI folder... ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, a user can bypass the authentication and directly access the web service.

The ISAPI folder is the special folder within the SharePoint hive where all WCF services should be deployed. This folder is mapped to the “_vti_bin” alias in the IIS, so that services deployed to this folder can be accessed through http://{SiteUrl}/_vti_bin/{ServiceName}.svc.

IIS handles base HTTP requests, but Windows SharePoint Services implements an Internet Server API (ISAPI) filter (STSFLTR.DLL) that modifies IIS behavior to handle managed paths, or inclusions and exclusions. The ISAPI filter either redirects requests to the Windows SharePoint Services ISAPI extension, or it allows ASPX pages (.aspx) and Web service URLs (.asmx) to fall through the filter to the SharePoint ASP.NET handler.

[image]

Comment: That means if we have another anonymous enabled website (site collection) then user may able to get to the services